# add users to firebase database after auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am looking for ways to do following:
Whenever a user registers or logs on for first time, then a record should be created in DB with the user's email-id.

Can someone please give directions, I have tried few options from my side, but none worked out correctly.

Comment: I do not understand your question, can you provide more details?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: The best way is to do your job is to create a function in Google Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

so do this,

from your question i conclude that you do not have a separate form for adding new users.
in such case ,
when the user clicks on the logon button,
u can check from the database if the record exists.
for eg. query a simple sql statement 
select * from users where email-id="entered value"

if it exists then open the main application 
else if it doesn't exists then insert a row with the entered values and then open the application.

Answer (score 0):

[image]**To Register User And Add Information to database**

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    DataBaseRefrence ref = FirebaseData.getInstance().getReference();
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)addOnCompleteListener(context, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

    if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
    FirebaseUser fUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    User user = new User(name,email);
    ref.child("Users").child(fuser.getUid).setValue(user);
}
```

**User class**

```
public class User
{
public String Name;
public String Email;

// need empty constractor

public User()
{}

public User(String name,String email)
{
Name = name;
email = email;
}

public String getName()
{
return Name;
}

public String getEmail()
{
return Email;
}
```

**To Get Value**

```
DataBaseRefrence ref = FirebaseData.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseUser fUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
ref.child("Users").child(fUser.getUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if(user!=null)
                 {
                  // do what ever you want
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

To Get data from firebase you have to go from child to child
for example to get userdata myRefLinkis *https://stackoverflow.com*

*https://stackoverflow.com/Users/UserId now get the data*

Comment: what structure would you need in databases

Comment: First Root -> child -> values
Or Root - > child -> child -> pushValues ->values

Comment: check in firebase docs, they explain very clear how to structure basic data

Comment: root -> users ?

Comment: in value of users that I put

Comment: yes, also give me a plus point for giving you all of this information

Comment: This approach has an issue in that the two sources may get out of sync as it's not guaranteed the database will accept and store the record. You need to handle rollback if making sure they are kept in sync is important to you